# Dijit NumberTextBox not setting Value

Tags: javascript, dojo

Using a Dojo / Dijit NumberTextBox from Javascript, I have line which reads:

```
dijit.byId(id).set('value', value);
```

where the id refers to a valid item, and value = **"1"** (a string).

However, this command doesn't actually *set* the value (it remains *undefined*), leading to errors later. I've proved this by examining the item immedaitelay after this command executes.

By comparison, a dijit TextBox or TextArea works fine.

Any ideas why not? Thanks

Comment: are you sure id is correctly set?  set a breakpoint there and inspect that byId is returning.

Answer (score 0):

value can be a string or int... for example, i created this number textbox, the current value is 2...

[image: Number Textbox creation]

so... now in console i test:

[image: test on console]

if error = "set value of undefined", that's because you are typping a wrong id...

Answer (score 0):

What is the error that you are getting?? Take a look at this link it might help you

```
http://jsfiddle.net/cFuV4/32/
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="anyText"></div>
```

**JS**

```
require([
    "dijit/form/NumberTextBox"
], function (TextBox) {
    var box = new TextBox({
        name: "any",
        value: "",
        //placeholder: "Type anything here"
    }, "anyText");

    box.set("value",'1');
});
```

Comment: Not getting any error. The 'by id' works, as I can examine the object before and after the set value instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the answer was simple and obvious....

Adding `parseInt()` around the supplied value string did it.

Hope this helps others.